# I was refused landing in Ireland and banned for 5 years

Tags: customs-and-immigration, ireland, south-african-citizens, deportation

I was refused landing in Ireland from South Africa and banned for 5 years. I was about to be deported, but I contacted the agent who brought me to Ireland and informed him that I was to be deported the following day and he took me to the UK.

I did a human rights claim but was refused by the home office and got immigration bail. If I want to appeal on it, I have to do it from outside of the UK, and I have got less than 28 days left to do so. Now I want to know if I can go back to Ireland and appeal from there?

Comment: What does ‘the agent who brought me to Ireland’ mean?

Comment: @Traveller Usually means human trafficker, visa racketeering agent, con man etc. In the immigration context it rarely means any good thing.

Comment: @ThE iLIEgAl aLiEn Yes :-) There was more than a hint of a rhetorical question there!

Comment: @Traveller I was aware. My answer was more a hint to the original poster.

Comment: What was your original purpose for travelling to Ireland? If you had concerns regarding your human rights, why did you not make an asylum claim when you reached Ireland (and why did you wait until you reached the U.K. to do so)?

Comment: What I don't understand is that if you were refused entry to Ireland from S.A., then how did you cross into the UK? where specifically did you enter the UK from?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Now I want to know if I can go back to Ireland and appeal from there?

You were in the process of being deported from Ireland but absconded because of a lack of border controls and entered UK where you fought an ultimately fruitless battle to obtain residence in UK.

Now some time after the fact, you want to similarly exploit the porous (or nonexistent) border back to Ireland and resurrect your dead petition in a zombie like fashion?

> I was refused landing in Ireland from South Africa and banned for 5
>   years.

Barring a major miracle it will not be successful. Remember, **per your own acknowledgement you have already been banned for five years.** You have become a serial flouter of immigration laws and processes. Your plight is worse than before.

Go back to South Africa and stop wasting years on long shot immigration ventures. Unfortunately the reality is that the world and Europe is becoming more anti-immigrant, particularly anti illegal immigrant which is the category you now fall in.

Additionally stop using **agents**, usually thats a euphemism for conmen and human traffickers with one mission, line their own pockets at anyone’s expense.

Comment: Uhm, have you even read his question? No, there's no "five years after the fact". He got a deporation notice with a 5 year ban, and now has 28 days left to appeal the ban. It says nothing about him trying to get residency in the UK. He also didn't escape deporation, since he did in fact leave the country. There is no general rule that one necessarily have to go back to the country of origin.

Comment: I cannot answer the question since I do not know the relevant laws for appealing entry bans. Neither do you, obviously, since you just shout out wild accusations without any basis. We do not even know why he was refused entry.

Comment: @bjorn I don’t need to know why he was refused entry. However I have commonsense and I know 1+1=2. When I see a pattern of abuse of immigration laws and agents and the like, I don’t need other irrelevant details to draw a conclusion. Maybe you do.

Comment: @bjorn A basic objective of a human rights claim would be to obtain leave to remain /residency.

Comment: @Traveller Actually no. You do not have a 'human right' to reside in any country. The country gets to decide who it wants to admit. The only way a 'human rights' appeal can work is if the process was discriminatory. That's why hardly any of them succeed.

Comment: @DJClayworth I agree - I’m referring to the claimant’s objective in making the claim, not the objective of a’human rights’ appeal per se

Comment: Wasn't complaining in anyway. Just looking for advice. Thanks for your advice The iLIEgAl aliEn it was very helpful "sort off"

Comment: @bjorn I understood the situation differently. He received a five year ban in Ireland. He then travelled to the U.K. where his asylum application was refused. He has 28 days in which to appeal that refusal to the Home Office.

Comment: "resurrect your dead petition in a zombie like fashion" --- "Your plight is worse than before" --- I had no idea this kind of language is acceptable.

Answer (score 7):

You say you're banned from Ireland for five years. That right there is the answer to the question of whether you can go to Ireland while you appeal the UK's refusal.

Comment: Yes i was banned but i left the country without them deporting me

Comment: @L.A.D, I don't get the subtext of that comment. Your original wording, "*I was refused landing in Ireland from South Africa and banned for 5 years*", doesn't suggest that there was anything conditional about the ban.